# Are there any differences between an event Action and an event Action initialized as a delegate in C#?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

```cs
public event Action<MyType> MyEvent;
public event Action<MyType> MyEvent = delegate { };
```

Are there any differences in C# between these two types of Events?

Comment: Well the first is null and the second is not null. What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: Well both of them can be subscribed to just the same no? I guess the difference is how I would call them. So the event only would be `MyEvent?.Invoke(foo)` while I guess the other wouldn't need the `?`. But is that it? I was thinking that perhaps there was more to it.